# Ramda js: lens for deeply nested objects with nested arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, ramda.js, lenses

Using Ramda.js (and lenses), I want to modify the JavaScript object below to change "NAME:VERSION1" to "NAME:VERSION2" for the object that has ID= "/1/B/i".

I want to use a lens because I want to just change one deeply nested value, but otherwise retain the entire structure unchanged.

I don't want to use lensIndex because I never know what order the arrays will be in, so instead, I want to "find" the object in an array by looking for its "id" fields.

Can I do this with lenses, or should I do it a different way?

```
{
  "id": "/1",
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": "/1/A",
      "apps": [
        {
          "id": "/1/A/i",
          "more nested data skipped to simplify the example": {} 
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "/1/B",
      "apps": [
        { "id": "/1/B/n", "container": {} },
        {
          "id": "/1/B/i",

          "container": {
            "docker": {
              "image": "NAME:VERSION1",
              "otherStuff": {}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }

  ]
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This should be possible by creating a lens that matches an object by ID which can then be composed with other lenses to drill down to the image field.

To start with, we can create a lens that will focus on an element of an array that matches some predicate (note: this will only be a valid lens if it is guaranteed to match at least one element of the list)

```
//:: (a -> Boolean) -> Lens [a] a
const lensMatching = pred => (toF => entities => {
    const index = R.findIndex(pred, entities);
    return R.map(entity => R.update(index, entity, entities),
                 toF(entities[index]));
});
```

Note that we're manually constructing the lens here rather than using `R.lens` to save duplication of finding the index of the item that matches the predicate.

Once we have this function we can construct a lens that matches a given ID.

```
//:: String -> Lens [{ id: String }] { id: String }
const lensById = R.compose(lensMatching, R.propEq('id'))
```

And then we can compose all the lenses together to target the image field

```
const imageLens = R.compose(
  R.lensProp('groups'),
  lensById('/1/B'),
  R.lensProp('apps'),
  lensById('/1/B/i'),
  R.lensPath(['container', 'docker', 'image'])
)
```

Which can be used to update the `data` object like so:

```
set(imageLens, 'NAME:VERSION2', data)
```

You could then take this a step further if you wanted to and declare a lens that focuses on the version of the image string.

```
const vLens = R.lens(
  R.compose(R.nth(1), R.split(':')),
  (version, str) => R.replace(/:.*/, ':' + version, str)
)

set(vLens, 'v2', 'NAME:v1') // 'NAME:v2'
```

This could then be appended to the composition of `imageLens` to target the version within the entire object.

```
const verLens = compose(imageLens, vLens);
set(verLens, 'VERSION2', data);
```

Comment: This is really easy to understand, and can be easy composed and/or modified. Thank you! For lensMatching, could that be replaced by: 

    `function lensMatching(pred) {
      return R.lens(
        R.find(pred),
        (newVal, array, other) => {
          const index = R.findIndex(pred, array);
          return R.update(index, newVal, array);
        }
      )
    }`

This seems a little easier for me to relate back to the lens documentation. But, am I missing something?

Comment: @GregEdwards That should work too. The main reason I suggested the other implementation was to prevent scanning the arrays twice (once in `find` and once in `findIndex`), however this shouldn't be a problem if the arrays are reasonably small.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, @ScottChristopher :) I am completely new to ramda, and functional programming at all, but isn't this a missing functionality in ramda? – to make a lens match by property value? I assume it is a quite common scenario, and would prefer to be able to just write the final compose-function directly as an array like this: `const imageLens = R.lensPath(['groups', {id: '/1/B'}, 'apps', {id: '/1/B/i'}, 'container', 'docker', 'image'])`

Comment: @aweibell There are plenty of lenses (among other functions) that can be constructed using the primitives offered by Ramda that aren't included in the library. It gets a little tricky with lenses like the one proposed because you need to ensure the lens will always match their focus, which can't be guaranteed by a general purpose library (e.g. what would it match for an empty array?)

Comment: @ScottChristopher OK, I thought that problem would occur with the included functions as well, like the valid (AFAIK) `lensPath(['groups', 1, 'apps', 1, 'container', 'docker', 'image'])`?

Comment: @aweibell You're right, functions like `R.lensIndex` fall into a similar category, though their usefulness was deemed to outweigh the potential risk of non-totality. If you feel similarly for this function then I'd suggest raising an issue or PR on the ramda/ramda github repo to propose the idea to the wider Ramda community.

Answer (score 10):

Here's one solution:

```
const updateDockerImageName =
R.over(R.lensProp('groups'),
       R.map(R.over(R.lensProp('apps'),
                    R.map(R.when(R.propEq('id', '/1/B/i'),
                                 R.over(R.lensPath(['container', 'docker', 'image']),
                                        R.replace(/^NAME:VERSION1$/, 'NAME:VERSION2')))))));
```

This could be decomposed into smaller functions, of course. :)

Comment: Is there a way to not have the query so deeply nested? Using "compose" or...?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which makes it more clear how to use over, map and when nicely.